# Помочь разобраться с кодом игры Pong на kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Имеется код на python:

```
  from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
        ObjectProperty
    from kivy.vector import Vector
    from kivy.clock import Clock


    class PongPaddle(Widget):
        score = NumericProperty(0)

        def bounce_ball(self, ball):
            if self.collide_widget(ball):
                vx, vy = ball.velocity
                offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
                bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
                vel = bounced * 1.1
                ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


    class PongBall(Widget):
        velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
        velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
        velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

        def move(self):
            self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


    class PongGame(Widget):
        ball = ObjectProperty(None)
        player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

        def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
            self.ball.center = self.center
            self.ball.velocity = vel

        def update(self, dt):
            self.ball.move()

            # bounce of paddles
            self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
            self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

            # bounce ball off bottom or top
            if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
                self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

            # went of to a side to score point?
            if self.ball.x < self.x:
                self.player2.score += 1
                self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
            if self.ball.x > self.width:
                self.player1.score += 1
                self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

        def on_touch_move(self, touch):
            if touch.x < self.width / 3:
                self.player1.center_y = touch.y
            if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
                self.player2.center_y = touch.y


    class PongApp(App):
        def build(self):
            game = PongGame()
            game.serve_ball()
            Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
            return game


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        PongApp().run()введите`введите сюда код` сюда код
```

Весь код взят и официальной документации на Kivy.org.

Я не могу понять, как работает класс PongPaddle и PongBall

Также не совсем понимаю строчку .kv файла:

```
PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width-self.width
        center_y: root.center_y
```

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста?

Comment: Уточните, что вы не понимаете?

Comment: Я не понимаю как работают эти два класса, не могли бы вы вкратце каждую строчку пояснить? Все нужно разобраться в этом коде!